# why is $-2x^{-5}$ simplified to $\frac{-2}{x^{5}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was asked to simplify $-2x^{-5}$

The teacher put up $\frac{-2}{x^{5}}$ as the answer. Why is this?

Comment: Because $x^{-n}=\frac{1}{x^n}$. Just ignore the $-2$.

Comment: Rules of exponents. Why your teacher thinks the fraction form is "to simplify" I don't know.

Comment: It's common in elementary algebra classes for exercises to include the direction, "write the result using positive exponents only," so as to exercise this exact equivalence. The teacher may be using the phrase "simplify" as (slightly sloppy) shorthand for this directive.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $x$ negative five times is the same as dividing by $x$ five times.

Answer (score 0):

Because $\alpha  x^{-n}=\alpha\frac{1}{x^n}$ in your case $\alpha=-2$ and $n=5$

For an arbitrary integer $n$ and nonzero $x$:

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily consider that simplified, but the two terms are equal. Recall that $x^{-a} = \frac{1}{x^a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the law of exponent $x^{-a}=\frac{1}{x^a}$(Negative Power).

Negative exponents signify division. In particular, find the reciprocal of the base, keep the exponent with the original base, and drop the negative.

For your question "why $-2x^{-5}=\frac{-2}{x^5}$?". The answer is simply as this:

Applying the law we have,

$x^{-5}=\frac{1}{x^5}$.

Then multiply $\frac{1}{x^5}$ by $-2$ we get,

$-2x^{-5}=\frac{-2}{x^5}$.